# Split not working with TAB character

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm trying to split the following string using `/t` character.

```
string bounces = "BounceEmail\tBounceType\tBounceDate\tBounceDescription\r\nuiohouih@gmaipuohuiphil.comj\tHARD_BOUNCE\t2016-07-01
 16:50:26\t\r\nuiohouih@gmaipuohuiphil.comj\tHARD_BOUNCE\t2016-07-01
 16:50:26\t"
```

But to my surprise the following command does not work and I get an array of only one element which is the same string above:

```
string[] columns = bounces.Split('\t');
```

**UPDATE**: Here is the full function to convert the content of a CSV file to a `DataTable`

```
public static DataTable GetCsvStringAsDataTable(string csvContent, char delimeter)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        string[] linesArr = csvContent.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
        foreach (var line in linesArr)
            lines.Add(line);
        if (lines.Count == 0)
            return null;
        string headerLine = lines[0];
        string[] columns = headerLine.Split(delimeter);
        lines.RemoveAt(0);
        for (int col = 0; col < columns.Length; col++)
            dt.Columns.Add(columns[col].Trim());
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var cols = line.Split(delimeter);
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < cols.Length; cIndex++)
                dr[cIndex] = cols[cIndex].Trim();
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**: This is the input string as I receive from the API.

[image]

Comment: Your code given here does work. Do you load the string from a file? What does it really contain?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I have updated the code with the entire function I am using. I simplified the code and that was probably not reasonable.

Comment: I get a data table with 4 rows.

Comment: Splitting on Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray produces empty strings when there is a \r\n in the input data. However adding a StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries produces a DataTable with exactly two rows of 4 columns as expected by the input data

Comment: I suggest to look at the input data with an hexdecimal viewer and check if the \t is present as a 0x09 value and not with two separate chars \ and t

Comment: @Steve makes sense. What do you think I should replace it with?

Comment: If you are unsure about the line terminator char (some file from Unix land comes with just \n) just add StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries

Comment: Contrary to popular belief using `Environment.NewLine` is not always recommended. You need to __know__ what the real delimiters are and then split by those that are actually present. A quick fix is `lines = text.Replace("\r\n", "\r").Replace(\r","\n").Split('\n');`

Comment: At first I got the same results as the poster, 1 element array - when prefixing the string variable with a `@`. In removing it, I got all the elements. But the poster did not define its string with `@` anyway...

Comment: @TaW Sorry, but still receive a string array of one element.

Comment: Can you post the input file? And the code that loads it

Comment: _receive a string array of one element_ For what element? `linesArr`?

Comment: @steve input does not come from a file. It's a *tab-separated* string returned from an API and it comes as I posted above.

Comment: @TaW yes. This is before splitting by tab.

Comment: So the splitting by __any__ of those 3 characters does not work? Sounds like they are not there after all, or maybe no longer after receiving it? Do try to look into it with a Hex tool and also double check the API docs!

Comment: @TaW I updated the question with a screenshot of what I receive from the API. Is it still important what I receive so long as it is a tab-separated string?

Comment: You are showing the source string, what did you expect to see? try showing the data table...

Comment: Well if it were really tab separated it would be split, at least into the header columns, right? Look at [this post to see how you can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185241/how-do-i-see-the-hex-values-of-a-string-in-a-vs2008-watch-window) look at the hex values of a string inside VS! Put a breakpoint at the start of the `GetCsvStringAsDataTable` methos and look into the `csvContent` parameter

Comment: Well your screenshot shows the \ and the t as __two__ characters. So you get the data wrong. A real TAB would be shown as a tab space! The same is true for the new line and form feed characters..

Comment: @TaW makes sense. So do you think I am receiving bad data from the API?

Comment: Yes. You get wrong data.

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty to improve your function a bit.
My version accepts both col delimiter and row delimiter:

```
public static DataTable GetCsvStringAsDataTable(string csvContent, char[] rowDelimeter, char[] colDelemiter)
{
    try
    {
        var lines = csvContent.Split(rowDelimeter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (lines.Length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var header = lines[0];

        var columns = header.Split(colDelemiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(column);
        }
        foreach (var line in lines.Skip(1))
        {
            var cols = line.Split(colDelemiter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            dt.Rows.Add(cols);
        }
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
var rowDelimeter = new char[] { '\r', '\n' };
var colDelemiter = new char[] { '\t' };
var dt = GetCsvStringAsDataTable(bounces, rowDelimeter, colDelemiter);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I still receive one element only and it is the entire input string.

Comment: @Steve Good catch!, it's basically just a copy-paste with minor modifications, so I didn't catch that.

Comment: sure. Thanks. Will replace your improved version as soon as I fix the main issue.